# rotate text in {align} formula, move {cases} to back, and wrap text

Tags: align, rotating, cases, wrap

I'm writing some formulas where I would like to move the `cases` bracket to the back, rotate some text, and wrap some text, among other things. I've made a working example of how far a got and a accompanying illustrations of where I would like to go (more or less). I am asking this community as my experience is that there's always a much simpler way to it (code at bottom of post).

Here's what I currently got
[image: where I am]

This is where I could like to go (doesn't have to look exactly like this, and the green is simply to illustrate what I've changed)
[image: where I would like to go]

This is my code for the above example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 \text{This sectors} &=
   \begin{cases}
  \text{ A markets}
  \begin{cases}
   4+3+4c        &  \\
   1+3+4c       & Q^*
  \end{cases}\\
  \text{ B markets}
  \begin{cases}
   1+3+m        &  \\
  5+3+4c       & N^*, F^*
  \end{cases}
    \end{cases}
  \\
 \text{Thats sectors} &=
 \begin{cases}
  \text{ C markets and some}
  \begin{cases}
   1+3+m         &  \\
   +3+4c         &  F^*
  \end{cases}\\
  \text{ D markets}
  \begin{cases}
   1+3+m         &  \\
   +3+4c         &  P^*
  \end{cases}\\
  \text{ E markets}
  \begin{cases}
   1+3+m         &  F1^*\\
      1+3+m         &  \\
   +3+4c         &  F2^*
  \end{cases}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The main gold is to make it all be more compact (mainly not so wide) and to add a `{cases}` to the right. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

It is generated by help of nested arrays.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\rotatebox[]{90}{\text{This sectors}} 
    &   \left[\begin{array}{p{22mm}l}
        A markets   &   \left[\begin{array}{l}
                                4+3+4c  \\
                                1+3+4c
                                \end{array}\right\} Q  \\[3ex]
        B markets   &   \left[\begin{array}{l}
                                1+3+m   \\
                                5+3+4c 
                                \end{array}\right\} N^*, F^*
        \end{array}\right.      \\
\rotatebox[]{90}{\text{Thats sectors}}
    &   \left[\begin{array}{p{22mm}l}
        C markets\newline
        and some    &   \left[\begin{array}{l}
                                        1+3+m   \\
                                        5+3+4c
                                \end{array}\right\} F^*         \\[3ex]
        D markets    &   \left[\begin{array}{l}
                                1+3+m   \\
                                +3+4c
                                \end{array}\right\} P^*         \\[3ex]
    E markets    &   \left[\begin{array}{@{\,}l}
                                \left.\begin{array}{@{}l}
                            1+3+m   \\
                            1+3+m
                                \end{array}\right\} F1^*    \\[2ex]
                                \left.\begin{array}{@{}l}
                                \phantom{1}+3+4c
                                    \end{array}\right\} F1^*
                                \end{array}\right.
        \end{array}\right.  
\end{align*}
    \end{document}
```